# metro-file-map: Watchman crawl failed

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, metro-bundler, watchman

**This is not a duplicate!**

I am new to react-native, and I started a new project yesterday using Expo, and it was running fine yesterday - I worked on the navigation and added darkmode - and everything was running perfectly both on web and mobile ... until I woke up today to this.

```
metro-file-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: query failed: synchronization failed: Connection timed out. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.
```

I followed the steps that some of the SO answers for similar watchman questions:

```
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ watchman shutdown-server
```

I also added watchman to dependencies, and a .watchmanconfig file.

But no, nothing seems to work for me, and I can't resume my work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work by removing watchman.